# Disable "inspect popup" menu entry in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to disable the "Inspect popup" menu option in an extension I'm working on. How can I do that? 
I now it's possible because I have some extensions installed that have this option disabled (e.g. "Send to Kindle" by klip.me).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "[Inspect popup](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup)" option is only available when:

1. **Developer mode** is activated (at `chrome://extensions/`).
2. The button has a popup associated (either via `default_popup` in the manifest file, or via [`chrome.browserAction.setPopup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setPopup)).

When requirement 1 is not met, the "Inspect popup" option is **invisible**.
When requirement 2 is not met, the "Inspect popup" option is disabled (greyed out).

The example you're referring to ("Send to Kindle") has no popup, failing criteria 2, hence it has no "Inspect popup" option.

Comment: That's all I need to know. Thank you Rob!