# Code in popup.js not being run (chrome/edge extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Related to:

[The Chrome extension popup is not working, click events are not handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601615/the-chrome-extension-popup-is-not-working-click-events-are-not-handled)

[Javascript in Google Chrome popup extension not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169285/javascript-in-google-chrome-popup-extension-not-running)

[Cannot get Chrome popup.js to use console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858909/cannot-get-chrome-popup-js-to-use-console-log)

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "*://*.youtube.com/*",
    ],
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "popup/popup.html"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "My extension"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background/background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": [
            "content/content.js"
        ],
        "matches": [
            "<all_urls>",
            "*://*.youtube.com/*"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": true,
        "match_about_blank": true
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "*.html",
        "images/*"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

`popup.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Extension</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>dkafafdafldafkla This shows</div>
</body>

<script src="popup.js">
</script>

</html>
```

`popup.js`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  console.log("Adding dom load event listener; we don't get here :(");
  chrome.tabs.create({
    active: true,
    url: "https://my.site.com/",
  });
});
```

The extension does not seem debugable:

[image]

There are no errors in the console (both web page and background scripts); why isn't the url opened when the popup is clicked (the text form popup.html appears in the new tab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it running as intended; removed `chrome_url_overrides` from `manifest.json` above and added the following to `background.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
  console.log("Current tab: ", tab.url);
  if (tab.url === "edge://newtab/") {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {
      url: "https://my.site.com/",
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description and the manifest code you provided, and the screenshot shows the "Inspect popup" option is disabled (greyed out), so I think your problem is that there is no `"default_popup"` declaration in the `manifest`. Or you can use [chrome.browserAction.setPopup](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#method-setPopup) to solve the problem.

This is a similar case：[Disable "inspect popup" menu entry in chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333323/disable-inspect-popup-menu-entry-in-chrome-extensions).

Comment: Added the `default_popup` the html is shown but the code in `popup.js` is not run. Added an answer; not sure if it's consistent with chrome extension design.